# Default time in bootstrap timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-timepicker

I'm using bootstrap timepicker

[image]

I want to display default time in timepicker not in textfield

```
   jQuery('.timepicker').timepicker({
          orientation: 'top',
          defaultTime: '11:59 PM',
          showInputs: false,
          minuteStep: 60
     });
```

Using this code to display default time but default time is shown on textfield also

Comment: @BoBiTza: I don't want to display default time in textfield only timepicker should contain default values when user clicks on timepicker then it should copy to textfield, like in my case 11:59 is default but it should not be in textfield by default

Comment: This depends on what timepicker you use, give us documentation of that plugin

Comment: @BoBiTza Using bootstrap timepicket Link: https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

Comment: Or you can try an `$('.timepicker').val(''); ` after your script